# Trying to chain 4 routers together.. possible?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, dmz

I have comcast 50mb internet and 3 other routers that I am trying to connect throughout my duplex house. I am running 50 ft cat5 cables to them throughout the house and have them powered on and connected. The modem that is initially hooked to the coax cable is also a router.. an Apple extreme n router is hooked to the comcast modem/router.. Linksys g router hooked to the Apple extreme and a netgear n router is hooked to the linksys. Im pretty sure they are still showing their original wireless connection names on my pc, but i want them all to just run off the one wifi connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Looking for single network wifi.. basically extending the range throughout

I was looking at something like this for assistance but not exactly sure.. I am pretty well educated when it comes to internet and routers as far as port forwarding, but this is a little out of my element.. Thanks
http://www.pcwintech.com/how-setup-two-or-more-routers-together-port-forwarding-port-triggering

Comment: You only need one [router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) because you only have two IP networks to route between, your LAN and the Internet. You may be able to configure the other devices to not be routers but to act only as [switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch), [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)s or [WiFi-repeaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater).

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is configure all your wireless routers that you have cabled up throughout the house as Access Points instead of routers. To do this, disable DHCP and NAT and let the comcast router do the DHCP and routing on the network. You can give each AP its own unique SSD so it is clear where it is located so you know which one you want depending on where you are (ie, nw_ap, sw_ap). It would also be advisable to set each AP's IP address manually outside of the DHCP range and set it as a reserved on the comcast router for its respective AP's MAC address (ie, keep 192.168.0.2-5 as your APs and start DHCP at 192.168.0.50).

Comment: If you use the same SSID and security your devices will seamlessly jump to the AP with the strongest signal.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is handled by wifi repeaters which pickup an already present 'master' signal and push it futher out. I don't think that port forawrding is going to unify all of your networks under one universal wifi network, which seems like what you are trying to do. Some wireless routers have repeating modes built into them, but it must be enabled first and pointed at the preferred network you want to repeat. However, most consurmer grade wifi routers don't come with this out of the box, but custom firmware such as DD-WRT can often add this functionality if your router is supported.

Comment: Lee has a point, but wireless is flaky enough without adding repeaters into the mix. If you are able to run cables, then multiple access points with the same SSID and security is a much more reliable option.

Answer (score 0):

RedGrittyBrick's comment is correct, and I have done this in the past myself. Like he said, disable DHCP and NAT, ignore the WAN/ADSL port and they will act just like a normal ethernet switch.

They will probably all need a static IP address set because they are more than just a switch. Once each one is set to an address that you know won't interfere with other devices (i.e. make sure it's out of the main router's DHCP range and not the same as any other static IP in use on your network), you can plug them all together using the normal LAN ports.

To use them as multiple access points, just make sure they are all set to broadcast the same SSID (wireless network name) and have the same security type and password. This way your wireless devices will jump between them automatically and you will experience a seamless connection.

It's a bit of a faff because you're not really using the routers like they are designed to be used, but I've had a system like that working in a previous house for over a year. I even sold the setup to the new tenant when I moved out!